# Get the list of EXISTS flags, by the list of IDs

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Get the list of EXISTS flags, by the list of IDs from the database using Room.

I need to get a list of the same size, in which if the element is not in the database, false will be stored, and if there is, true

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FavoriteCharacter WHERE id IN (:ids))")
fun existsRx(ids: List<Int>): List<Boolean>
```

I tried to do it this way, however, I get a list of one element.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite query you want is probably something like this:

```sql
SELECT id, id IN (:ids) AS id_has
FROM FavoriteCharacter
```

This would return every `id` in your table, along with a *boolean* value as to whether or not that `id` value is also contained in the input list of integers.

I'm not a Room guru, so I don't know exactly how your method signature would need to change.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to get a list of the same size, in which if the element is not in the database, false will be stored, and if there is, true

Comment: @AntonTikhonov Then the `:ids` value really belong in a table somewhere.  I suggest fixing your design issues in this case.